# make a form action to another page without losing the information

Tags: php, html

I want to make a form which takes information then uses that information on another page when it is submitted. However once it redirects, it loses all the information from the other page for example:

Page 1:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {$info=$_POST['info'];}
?>

<html>
  <form action='page2.html' method='POST'>
    <input name='info'>
    <intput type='submit' name='submit'>
  </form>
</html>
```

Page2:

```
<?php
      echo $info;
?>
```

it doesn't know what the variable 'info' is on page 2.

Comment: is your server configured to treat `.html` files as php scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 { echo $_POST['info'];}
```

and remove:

```
 echo $info;
```

Now reasons:

When you submit a form it's redirected to a page written in `action` attribute of `form` tag and sends form data to it. So after submitting form you are on the `page2` where you have access to `posted` data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting to `page2.html` then your form data will be in the global `$_POST` variable. Try

`print_r($_POST);`

in your `page2.html` php

Answer (score 0):

in page 2:

```
echo $_POST['info'];
```

I don't know why you have the variables $_POST in the first page. Also you should name the page2 `page2.php` unless you have configured it otherwise in your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Page 1:

```
<html>
  <form action='page2.html' method='POST'>
    <input name='info'>
    <intput type='submit' name='submit'>
  </form>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
echo $_POST['info'];
```

Or, to see everything that's passed between pages:

```
print_r($_POST);
```